# Estoy tratando de que mediante un imagButton ubicado en un fragment de un Button Navigation ir a una Activity que contiene un RecycleView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, kotlin

Este es el error que me muestra el compilador:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton{536c46 VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,128-520,618 #7f080245 app:id/imageButtonBar} does not have a NavController set.

Este es mi codigo de mi xml:

`<ImageButton

```
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="245dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@mipmap/bares"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />`
```

Este es mi codigo del click:

`override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState )

```
    imageButtonBar.setOnClickListener {
        it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_menuFragment_to_bares)
    }


}`
```

Answer (score 0):

En el onCreate() debes inicializar el NavController y luego en el onClick acceder
al `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_menuFragment_to_bares)`
Sin el it.

Otra solución es directamente instanciar el NavController en el onClick() aunque es una mala práctica:

```
imageButtonBar.setOnClickListener {
Navigation.findNavController(this, 
R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_menuFragment_to_bares)
}
```

this --> referencia a la actividad (Que seguramente al estar en un onClick, la referencia la obtiene del View, por lo que considera cambiarlo a la referencia de la actividad)
R.id.nav_host_fragment --> id de tu NavHostFragment
R.id.action_menuFragment_to_bares --> id del fragment agregado a tu grafico de navegación